# ¿Como obtener el elemento que contiene mayúsculas de un Array con Powershell?

Tags: array, powershell

Necesito obtener el elemento que contiene mayúsculas de un Array mediante Powershell.

Ejemplo:

`Array = {a:1, a:2, a:3, A:4, a:5}`

Necesito extraer el dato A:4, el cual no siempre estará en la posición 3 del Array, mediante PowerShell.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aquí tienes una solución utilizando el operador `-cmatch`. En este caso, en powershell existen los operadores `-match` `-imatch` y `-cmatch` que distinguen entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, etc. En este caso, utilizando `cmatch` y el patrón regular `[A-Z]` parece suficiente.

Esta es la nota que indican en la documentación:

> Traditionally, regular expressions are case sensitive by default. This
>   is true for the .NET framework too. However, it is not true in
>   PowerShell. -match and -replace are case insensitive, as are -imatch
>   and -ireplace. For case sensitive matching, use -cmatch and -creplace.
>   I recommend that you always use the “i” or “c” prefix to avoid
>   confusion regarding case sensitivity.

Es decir, que en el caso de Powershell, parece que -match y -replace son case Insensitive, y por tanto, debes utilizar `cmatch`

[Aquí la documentación de `cmatch`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html)

Aquí el script de ejemplo:

```
#Creamos el objeto array 
$ARRAY = @("a:1" , "a:2", "a:3", "A:4", "a:5")
Write-Output "Primer array $($ARRAY)"
$detected = $false;
#Lo recorremos, y utilizamos el operador -match
For ($i=0; $i -lt $ARRAY.count ; $i++)
{
    if( $ARRAY[$i] -cmatch "[A-Z]" )
    {
        Write-Output "La posición con mayúsculas es $($i+1)"
        Write-Output "El valor recuperado es $($ARRAY[$i])"
        Write-Output "La letra localizada es $($Matches.Values[0])"
        $detected = $true;
    }

}

if(-Not $detected)
{Write-Output "El Array no contiene mayúsculas"}


$ARRAY = @("A:4","a:1" , "a:2", "a:3",  "a:5")
Write-Output "Segundo array $($ARRAY)"
$detected = $false;
For ($i=0; $i -lt $ARRAY.count ; $i++)
{
    if( $ARRAY[$i] -cmatch "[A-Z]" )
    {
      Write-Output "La posición con mayúsculas es $($i+1)"
      Write-Output "El valor recuperado es $($ARRAY[$i])"
      Write-Output "La letra localizada es $($Matches.Values[0])"
      $detected = $true;
    }  
}

if(-Not $detected)
{Write-Output "El Array no contiene mayúsculas"}

$ARRAY = @("a:4","a:1" , "a:2", "a:3",  "a:5")
Write-Output "Tercer array $($ARRAY)"
$detected = $false;
For ($i=0; $i -lt $ARRAY.count ; $i++)
{
    if( $ARRAY[$i] -cmatch "[A-Z]" )
    {
      Write-Output "La posición con mayúsculas es $($i+1)"
      Write-Output "El valor recuperado es $($ARRAY[$i])"
      Write-Output "La letra localizada es $($Matches.Values[0])"
      $detected = $true;
    }
}

if(-Not $detected)
{Write-Output "El Array no contiene mayúsculas"}
```

Aquí la salida del script

```
PS C:\Users\Alejandro\Downloads> C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\test.ps1
Primer array a:1 a:2 a:3 A:4 a:5
La posición con mayúsculas es 4
El valor recuperado es A:4
La letra localizada es A
Segundo array A:4 a:1 a:2 a:3 a:5
La posición con mayúsculas es 1
El valor recuperado es A:4
La letra localizada es A
Tercer array a:4 a:1 a:2 a:3 a:5
El Array no contiene mayúsculas
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfectamente!